# How do I find out what is forcing php errors to show on page

Tags: php, .htaccess, error-suppression

I have a few small scripts installed on my server and was trying to debug yesterday. To show errors on page I set Display_errors= on in the phpsettings of my cloudlinux cpanel. this didn't show errors on page and after trying out different php versions I gave up for a few hours. When I came back to give it another try I noticed that php errors were showing on my pages.

This was the first thing I couldn't understand.

After much time spent on slowly debugging I am down to only a few minor notices and errors and I would like to turn off php errors again untill I can get back to the rest in a few days or possibly weeks.

I went back to set display_errors= off in my cloudlinux cpanel but all errors are still showing.

mysite.com/phpinfo.php shows diplay_errors is set to off. I have tried searching for any rogue php.ini files, but there are none. I cant find anything in my htaccess files either. The index.php files of my scripts are also not showing any error settings.

I have rebooted the server completely, cleared pc caches, tried multiple different devices, restarted apache. all to no avail.

Even with `ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');` at the top of my index.php file The errors are still showing

Link to page with errors: http://urlgone.com/162e2a/

Can anyone recommend how I can track down what is causing errors to display. Been stuck on this for hours and I feel like i'm just going in circles now.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php in particular if you'd want `error_reporting(0);` on a production machine, otherwise set the appropriate reporting level.

Comment: the top of my index.php looks like this: <?php 
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');   shouldn't it be impossible for there to be errors on this page?

Comment: Then all I could assume is the ability to change that setting has been denied, are you on shared hosting? is PHP safe mode enabled?